# How to implement the Polya-Aeppli distribution in Python using rv_discrete?

Tags: python, scipy, probability, poisson

I have tried to implement the Polya-Aeppli (Geometric Poisson) distribution in Python by specifying the PMF via subclassing the scipy.stats.rv_discrete class.

I have implemented it as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import rv_discrete
import numpy as np
import math

class PolyaAeppli(rv_discrete):

    def _pmf(self, k: np.ndarray, lambda_, theta_) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Probability mass function for Polya-Aeppli distribution. Extension of Poisson distribution for
        moddeling group arrivals.

        :param k: internal parameter of rv_discrete
        :param lambda_: arrival rate param of Poisson dist: [0, inf). The higher the lambda, the more arrivals
        :param theta_: probability param of Geometric dist: [0, 1]. The LOWER the theta, the more arrivals
        :return: probability values for each k
        """

        if isinstance(lambda_, np.ndarray or list):
            lambda_ = lambda_[0]. # depending on the situation, this is either a number or a list of the same number, so correct accordingly
        if isinstance(theta_, np.ndarray or list):
            theta_ = theta_[0]
        k = np.asarray(k, dtype=int)
        res = np.zeros(len(k))
        for ix, k_ in enumerate(k):  # sorry, cannot vectorize
            if k_ == 0:
                res[ix] = np.exp(-lambda_)
            else:
                res[ix] = np.exp(-lambda_) * np.sum([(np.power(lambda_, i) / math.factorial(i)) *
                                                     ((1 - theta_) ** (k_ - i)) * (theta_ ** i) *
                                                     (comb(k_ - 1, i - 1)) for i in range(1, k_ + 1)])
        return res
```

It is a little bit hacky because `k` is an `np.ndarray` when fed to `_pmf`, but that won't work with `range()`.
The mathematical formula seems correct, however when plotting samples with varying parameters, the results seem off:

```
    PA = PolyaAeppli(name='polya_aeppli')

    # sample from distribution
    resa = PA.rvs(lambda_=0.5, theta_=0.5, size=1000)
    resb = PA.rvs(lambda_=0.5, theta_=0.9, size=1000)
    resc = PA.rvs(lambda_=0.9, theta_=0.5, size=1000)
    resd = PA.rvs(lambda_=0.9, theta_=0.9, size=1000)

    # plot histogram

    plt.hist(resa, label='a', alpha=0.5)
    plt.hist(resb, label='b', alpha=0.5)
    plt.hist(resc, label='c', alpha=0.5)
    plt.hist(resd, label='d', alpha=0.5)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[polya-Aeppli results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw6AX.png)

I would expect `d` to have on average the largest number of arrivals, given both group size and arrivals rate are highest. But that does not seem to be the case.

Is something wrong in my code or am i just misunderstanding the distribution / results?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think the formulation is correct actually! I just got confused with the Theta parameter. Turns out the expected group size per arrival GROWS with decreasing Theta. So all good! Just leaving this here in case anybody needs to implement the Polya-Aeppli PMF in Python in the future.

(And if anybody can improve this very hacky code that's great).